# Can't able to load audio into android by using phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, limejs

I developed a game in html5 using limejs now i want to wrap into android using phonegap. I have done it very successfully and all my assets loaded greatly except audio. The audio is not loading into android.

The logcat shows as :

" 10-30 15:19:14.138: E/MediaPlayer(539): Error (1,-2147483648) "

Any idea about this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error pops up mostly when the encoding you are using for your file isn't supported. Try another file type, taking this in mind: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html